# Inserir um valor em uma variável no formulário

Tags: javascript, angular

Tenho um cadastro de grupo e subgrupo.

Meu idGrupo está recebendo um valor e tenho que inseri-lo no formulário para ir no post.

```
@Input() idGrupo: any;

configurarFormulario() {
    this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [null, Validators.required],
      groupItem: this.formBuilder.group({
         id: []
      })
    });
 }

  salvar() {

    this.service.postSubgroup(this.formulario.value);
    console.log(this.formulario.value);
   // console.log(`O id do grupo é esse: ${this.idGrupo}`);
  }
```

Ele deve enviar este json:

```
{
    "name": "test", **<- Input que vou mandar no post**
    "groupItem": {
        "id": 1      **<- id que nao consigo enviar**
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce pode usar o spread operator do es6

```
salvar() {
      this.service.postSubgroup({...this.formulario.value, id: this.idGroup});
}
```

Comment: Faltou eu passar a informação de como queria o json, mas já foi uma grande ajuda a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Meu código final ficou :

this.service.postSubgroup({
      ...this.formulario.value,
      groupItem: ({
        id: this.idGrupo
      })
    });